# Android background services stop responding after ~1 day

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-service

I'm building an app that has two background/foreground services:

1. Sync with API on FCM data notification - high priority
2. Physical activity monitoring using Activity Transition API

This app is also ignoring battery optimization(on the exemption list).

If app is terminated and devices put to sleep, these services function properly for about 24 hours. After then they both just stop.

Devices has no battery saver mode enabled, it's unpluged from charging and the battery is at 90%. The device is Samsung with Android 11. App is not on the sleep/deepsleep list.

I can't get my head around why these services just drop out after those ~24 hours. Based on Android documentation, app with ignored battery optimization shouldn't Doze. And FCM message with high priority should wake the app from Standby. When this happens nothing really helps, I have tried manually disabling standby using `adb` and put the device on charger. The only thing that helps is relaunching the app.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: So you must  figure out if your service is dead or running in an unresponsive state. Setup a debugger and logs to investigate. Is there anything in the service that could crash?

Comment: There is, but we have Crashlytics that would have reported this. And because this happens to both services, it must be something else.